# Vuetify v-slot:activator not stopping

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a text-field that's triggering a color-picker. This is inside a `v-for` loop as well. All is fine until the `activator` triggers the `color-picker` and multiple pickers are triggered with a mashup of the `v-for` data. [image: I printed the data to the screen so its easy to see]

You can see the mashup of data at the top, as well as mutliple color pickers activated.

Any idea why? My code is below:

```html
<v-tab-item>
  <v-card
    flat
    v-for="(colorMenu, index) in colorMenus"
    :key="index"
  >
    <v-card-text>
      <v-row 
        justify="start" 
        align="center">
        <v-col
          cols="4"
        >
        <p class="font-weight-bold text-subtitle-2 mt-4">{{ colorMenu.title }}</p>
        </v-col>
        <v-col
          cols="8"
        >
          <v-text-field 
            v-model="myModels[colorMenu.type]"
            v-mask="mask" 
            hide-details 
            class=""
            solo
          >
            <template 
              v-slot:append
            >
              <v-menu
                v-model="menu" 
                top 
                nudge-bottom="105" 
                nudge-left="16" 
                :close-on-content-click="false"
              >
                <template 
                  v-slot:activator="{ on }"
                >
                  <div
                    :style="{ backgroundColor: selectColors[index],  borderRadius: menu ? '50%' : '4px'}" 
                    v-on="on"
                    class="color_select"
                  />
                </template>
                    <v-color-picker
                      v-model="selectColors[index]" 
                      flat
                    >
                    </v-color-picker>
              </v-menu>
            </template>
          </v-text-field>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-divider class="mt-3"></v-divider>
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</v-tab-item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The main problem is all the `v-menu`'s are bound to the single `menu` Boolean, causing all the menus to open and close at the same time. To resolve this, make `menu` an array of Booleans (like you've done with the other props within the `v-for`).
2. Another issue is your `backgroundColor` is bound to `selectColors[index]`, but that's an object from the `v-color-picker`. The object has a `hex` property that contains the hex string of the color, which would be appropriate for the `backgroundColor` value.

```html
<v-menu                 
        v-model="menu[index]" 
        top 
        nudge-bottom="105" 
        nudge-left="16" 
        :close-on-content-click="false"
        >
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">                                       
    <div :style="{ backgroundColor: selectColors[index]?.hex,  borderRadius: menu[index] ? '50%' : '4px'}" 
          v-on="on"
          class="color_select"
          />
  </template>
  <v-color-picker v-model="selectColors[index]" flat>
  </v-color-picker>
</v-menu>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return { 
      menus: [],
      ⋮
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/NWwyBjd?editors=1010)